# Return multiple items from a Django View (ajax)

Tags: django, jquery, django-views

I have a function on my page that uses ajax. The ajax goes to a Django view, which can then return some sort of data for me. Unfortunately, I can only get it to return one piece of data at the moment. The second gets returned as the string "success". Here's what I have going:

Ajax:

```
 success: function(data, message) { 
            if(data === 'False'){
                    $('#mailsquare').css('background-color', '#A80000');
                    $('.dropdown-menu').prepend('<li class="message" id="{{item.id}}">'+message.substring(0,30)+'</li>');
            } else {
                    $('#mailsquare').css('background-color', '#1b1b1b');
            }
   },
```

View:

```
@login_required
def checkMail(request):

    user = request.user.get_profile()

    i = inbox.objects.get(user = user)
    read = i.read

    new = i.message.order_by('created')[:1]

    return HttpResponse(read, new)
```

The prepend statement doesn't use the "message" value that it is receiving, but rather just inserts the string "success". The "data" parameter is handled correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`success`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method is defined like this:

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
```

So, `message` is actually the `textStatus` Hence the result.

You need to send the data from the view correctly for this to work correctly.

One way to do it is:

```
@login_required
def checkMail(request):
    user = request.user.get_profile()
    read = inbox.objects.get(user = user).read    
    newest = i.message.order_by('created')[:1]

    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'read': read, 'newest': newest}))
```

and in the js

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
    var read = data.read;
    var newest = data.newest;
    //rest of the stuff    
}
```

Comment: It's [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) (instead HttpResponse) nowadays.

Comment: Simply do: `data = {'read': read, 'newest': newest}` And then: `return JsonResponse(data)`

Answer (score 0):

You wrong return the data for ajax

```
def answer(request):    
     # same you code
     payload = {'success':True,'param1': 'you_value', 'param2':'you_value2'}
     return HttpResponse(json.dumps(payload), content_type='application/json')
```

In Javascript

```
success: function(data) { 
        if(data.success === false){
                alert(data.param1);
                alert(data.param2);

        } else {
                $('#mailsquare').css('background-color', data.param1);
                $('#mailsquare').html(data.param2);
        }},
```